# while multiplying two number and storing into that number ends up with a result of NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list, nan, isnan

while iam using the += operator the multiplication results in NaN

```
 convertToDecimal(){
            let current=this.head;
            let size=this.size;
            size-=1;
            var result;
            while(current!=null){
                let num=current.value; 
                var power=Math.pow(2,size)
                result=(power*num);
                size-=1;
                current=current.next;
    
            }
            // console.log(result);
        }
```

****console without putting += for result**

value of result in each iteration

```
8
4
2
1
```

**but afer i puts +=**

```
result+=(power*num);
```

output is

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Anyone can explain this please, I am new to javaScript so may be its a dumb question

Comment: Could you edit your question and introduce a runnable snippet (using the toolbar button), so that the instance of your linked list is initialised and running the code reproduces the NaN outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your `result` variable has no initial value and so it starts as `undefined`. The first time you then execute `+=`, it tries to add a number to `undefined` which results in `NaN`.

Your problem can be reproduced with this simplified code:

```js
var result;

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result += 1;
    console.log(result);
}
```

So initialise as `var result = 0`.

```js
var result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result += 1;
    console.log(result);
}
```